# JSFiddle simple CSS code not working on localhost

Tags: css, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TTwtf/

This is some simple CSS that changes the display of a table using a media query. If width is less than a certain amount, it hides the table header, and will make each row of 5 columns display across 3 lines instead (2/2/1) . U can widen and narrow the window in jsfiddle and see it working.

I copy pasted the html into a blank html file.
I copy pasted the css into a blank css file.
I linked both using the following so that the html file looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsfiddle.css" />
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="cell-time">Booking Time</th>
.......
```

I'm testing it on my localhost in chrome. The table headers disappear however the table cells don't stack above one another like they do on jsfiddle. And I tested jsfiddle using the same chrome browser and it works on jsfiddle.

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's time for the [Chrome Debugger tool](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Try right clicking on the browser page where the table headers should be and select Inspect Element.  Using the debugging tool, you can then verify that the html and the CSS is as you expect it to be (and experiment with changes until things work as you'd like).

Comment: Yes i've done all of that and even inspected line for line the CSS that applied to the table tags (tr / th / td) and made comparisons between jsfiddle and my localhost. I cannot find any difference except all that extra bit of code that jsfiddle puts in there. 

Can you please try to copy paste the code into 2 separate files (html and css), link them  and tell me if it is working for u?